# Admin grid not shown in magento 2.3.5 version

Tags: magento2.3.5, custom-admin-grid

Admin grid not shown in magento 2.3.5 version

[image]

Comment: Have you check console or log file?

Comment: There is no console error

Comment: please contac the developer of the extension